# How can I add back Identity to a column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
    [QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [QuestionUId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL
);
```

QuestionId was a primary key and when I dropped the primary key then the identity seemed to drop also. Is there a way that I can get back (add) the identity as a default for this column and have it so the new value starts at a value greater than the existing values ?

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the primary key constraint from a table does not alter the `IDENTITY` property of the primary key column.

```
USE tempdb;
DROP TABLE dbo.Question;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Question
(
    QuestionID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Question PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , SomeData VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Question (SomeData) VALUES ('test');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Question;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Question DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Question;

INSERT INTO dbo.Question (SomeData) VALUES ('test2');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Question;
```

The code above creates a table with a primary key, then drops the primary key.  It then adds a row to the table; and as you can see in the results below, the new row contains an auto-generated IDENTITY value for the QuestionID column.

Results:

[image]

Be aware that you *could* use the SQL Server Management GUI to modify the `IDENTITY` property of the column in question, however behind the scenes, SSMS will actually drop and recreate the table, which might be problematic to say the least.

Answer (score -2):

The parameters of the `IDENTITY` allow you to seed the start value:

```
[QuestionId]       INT              IDENTITY (SEED_VALUE, INCREMENT) NOT NULL,
```

So get the MAX(QuestionId) from your table and use that + 1

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question of how to apply the `IDENTITY` property to an existing column.